# Unable to install and use Turf.js

Tags: javascript, turfjs

I want to use [booleanCrosses](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleancrosses) and [booleanContains](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleancontains) methods from Turf.js library in my application on the client side, but I fail. I first tried to download just [turf.min.js](https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf@4.4.0/turf.min.js), but when in my code I call `turf.booleanContains(...)` I get

> TypeError: turf.booleanContains is not a function

I also tried to download the whole turf archive and install needed packages with npm, but got a hell of error messages. So, what is the right way to install turf.js and some particular packages?

Comment: I'm also new to `npm` terminology and don't quite understand what they mean by this command: `npm install @turf/helpers @turf/buffer`. Should I replace `@turf` with a full path to the archive?

Comment: When for example I run this command `npm install @turf/helpers`, it works. When however I run `npm install @turf/boolean-crosses`, I get error messages.

Comment: Do you want to use it on the client side (in the browser) or server side (in nodejs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue and fixed this by using yarn. I had a stale turf index.d.ts in my node_modules (unclear why). I wish I could remember what I did precisely, but edit package.json (I put them out of order to irritate yarn - though that might not have done anything)

```
"@turf/boolean-contains": "^4.6.1",
"@turf/turf": "^4.6.1",
```

Then run `yarn` (yarn is a leaner, meaner substitute for npm install/update - install via npm i -g yarn and enjoy)

Now index.d.ts shows additional modules (including booleanContains which is my specific issue).

Import module like this:

```
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';
```

And use as documented.